# A question in set theory about intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true the followng?

Let $ \{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ and Y. Then $(\cap_{i \in I}A_i) \cap Y=\cap_{i \in I}(A_i\cap Y)$.

If yes i would like to see a rigorous proof. THANKS

Comment: Are you assuming that the index set $I$ is nonempty? Because if $I=\emptyset$  then the left side of your equation is $Y$ and the right side is the whole universe. Assuming a nonempty index set (as usual when dealing with intersections), everything is fine.

Comment: @bof Good point! To be honest: I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

It is true if $I\neq\varnothing$ (see the comment of @bof). If you can prove:$$x\in\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i}\right)\cap Y\iff\cdots\iff x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\left(A_{i}\cap Y\right)$$
then you are done and your proof is rigorous.

Give it a try yourself.